# How to compare results from different clustering models. Conceptual. No code

Tags: cluster-analysis

I have a conceptual question on cluster analysis.
I have a space with 700.000 samples and 7 variables.

How do I demonstrate that a cluster model built using all the (uncorrelated) variables have a better clustering power than the 7 monovariate models built on the 7 variables taken separately?

In other words, I want to compare the total variance of points around centroids,

I tried to compare the  SSE graphs. The conjunct model results to have an SSE curve well above the 7 monovariate model curves.

So much above that I am sure there is a conceptual problem in my reasoning. I suspect that distances in a 7D dimension space is not comparable with distances in 1D space. I tried to MinMax scale all the variables before clustering. But I still have the same problem. Maybe the SSE is not  the indicator I should use?

But then, if not the SSE, what other indicator should I use to demonstrate that the conjunct model leads to a lower variance of points around centroids?

Thanks for helping

PS: I tried to use the Silhouette coefficient. I have the same problem. I believe that I cannot compare Silhouette coefficients from different dimension spaces.

Comment: Always use all variables when evaluating?

Comment: no... When I use 1D clustering I only consider 1 variable. The clustering one.

Comment: Well, for obvious reasons that yields a much smaller SSE if you ignore variables.